# Implement of Google Analytic Android Privacy Policy And Opt-Out Policy in Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, privacy, policy

I search a lot then come to know how to implement Google Analytic Policy in your app, Please see my answer below, Here i explained Simplest way for beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to compile your app with Google analytic policy , below is my way just sharing knowledge Please up-vote if you found this useful.

**First add below lines into your Play Store App Description**

> To make "Your App Name" better,This application uses Google Analytics
>   to anonymously track usage data within the application.

**String.xml**

```
<string name="off">Off</string>
<string name="send_usage_statistics">Send anonymous usage statistics</string>
<string name="send_usage_summary">To make <Your App Name> better,This application uses Google Analytics to anonymously track usage data within the application.</string>
```

**In your Prefrence - xml (prefrence.xml)**

```
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="send_usage"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:title="@string/send_usage_statistics"
            android:summaryOn="@string/send_usage_summary"
            android:summaryOff="@string/off"/>
```

**In Your PrefrenceActivity.java**

```
private void initGoogleAnalytic(CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference){

        checkBoxPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                CheckBoxPreference swp = (CheckBoxPreference)preference;
                boolean isChecked=swp.isChecked();
                GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setAppOptOut(isChecked);
               // boolean isd=GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppOptOut();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Finally call above method as**

```
 initGoogleAnalytic((CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("send_usage"));
```